# Convert 24 bit two's complement to int?

Tags: c#, mono, integer, data-conversion, twos-complement

I have a C#/Mono app that reads data from an ADC. My read functions returns it as ulong. The data is in two complement and I need to translate it into int. E.g.:

```
0x7FFFFF = + 8,388,607
0x7FFFFE = + 8,388,606
0x000000 = 0
0xFFFFFF = -1
0x800001 = - 8,388,607
0x800000 = - 8,388,608
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const int MODULO = 1 << 24;
const int MAX_VALUE = (1 << 23) - 1;

int transform(int value) {
  if (value > MAX_VALUE) {
    value -= MODULO;
  }
  return value;
}
```

Explanation: `MAX_VALUE` is the maximum possible positive value that can be stored in 24 signed int, so if the value is less or equal then that, it should be returned as is. Otherwise value is unsigned representation of two-complement negative number. The way two-complement works is that negative number is written as a number modulo `MODULO`, which would effectively mean that `MODULO` is added. So to convert it back to signed we subtract `MODULO`.

Comment: Thanks. It works well for negative values, but, e.g., transform(0x7FFFFF) gives -8388609. Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: @CristianM For me it returns `8388607` as it should. `0x7FFFFF` is exactly `MAX_VALUE`, so the if statement is not executed. May be try to run again?

Comment: It works. I have to write it as const int MAX_VALUE = ((1 << 23) - 1). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest and fastest algorithm is by XORing with the (1 << 23) and then subtracting (1 << 23) from the result:

```
    const int Val = 1 << 23;
    
    int transform(int value) {  
      return (value ^ Val) - Val;
    }
```

Comment: Nice, can you explain why this works?

Comment: it is called sign extension suggested by Joe Zbiciak in 2010. Check http://aggregate.org/MAGIC/#Sign%20Extension

Comment: I suggest you edit your answer and include this information there for easier access.